# How to get a value from a property of a nested map with dot notation in Groovy using string interpolation

Tags: java, string, groovy, hashmap, string-interpolation

I receive a dot notated string from parameter, e.g. `"attr1.attr2.attr3"`.
I have an object of data type `LinkedHashMap<String, Object> mapObject`.
It has a value that can be accessed this way: `mapObject.attr1.attr2.attr3`.

When I try to access the field in this way: `mapObject."${attr1.attr2.attr3}`, I receive a `MissingPropertyException`, as groovy translates it as a String: `mapObject."attr1.attr2.attr3"` and that property, obviously, does not exist.
I have managed to solve it using the `Eval.java class Eval.x()` method this way:  `Eval.x(mapObject,"x.${attr1.attr2.attr3}")`, but this is too slow even for a snail.

Does there exist a way where I can get the value of a nested property of a map knowing only the dot notated path?

Here is my code:

```
def superCoolMethod(String dotNotatedPath, LinkedHashMap<String, Object> MapObject){
def valueINeedToGetFromTheMapObject = MapObject."${dotNotatedPath}"
// Other stuff unimportant for this question.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the path on `.` (quote it for the regexp) and then reduce
over the path using your data.  E.g.

```
def data = [a: [b: [c: 42]]]
def path = "a.b.c"

println path.split(/\./).inject(data){ m, p -> m?.getAt(p) }
// → 42
```